# Using bcrypt for passwords- forgotten password email

Tags: php, mysqli, bcrypt

I have recently implemented bcrypt for user passwords. I have managed to get the password to hash when the user registers, and they can login to their account with the password they registered with (not the hashed version) by comparing them against each other. My problem is- I am working on a forgotten password email page that sends an email to the user stating their password, HOWEVER it sends the hashed version. Is there any way around this that I could state the old one or is this impossible? I know this is not very safe, however it is only a small personal project I am completing and is not live.

Here is my forgot.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql="select * from user where email='$email'";
$result   = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $pass  =  $rows['password'];//FETCHING PASS
    //echo "your pass is ::".($pass)."";
    $to = $rows['email'];
    //echo "your email is ::".$email;
    //Details for sending E-mail
    $from = "Website";
    $url = "www.website.com";
    $body  =  "Password recovery
    -----------------------------------------------
    Url : $url;
    <br> Your email details: $to;
    <br>Here is your password  : $pass;
    <br><br>Sincerely,
    Find-a-room";
    $from = "myemail@email.com";
    $subject = "Password recovered";
    $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
    $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server\r\n";
    $sentmail = mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $headers1 );
   } else {
if ($_POST ['email'] != "") {
echo "<span> Not found your email in our database</span>";
    }
    }


if($sentmail==1)
{
    echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Your Password Has Been Sent To Your 
Email Address.</span>";
}
    else
    {
    if($_POST['email']!="")
    echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Cannot send password to your e-mail 
address.Problem with sending mail...</span>";
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label> Enter your User ID : </label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you hash the password (as you should) it is not possible to send it to the user anymore. Instead, create a one time token that allows the user to set a new password and send this token to the user.

Comment: No, you can't unless you save it in a format that is un-encryptable to you (which is a bad idea). Hashed values are NOT reversible.

Comment: If you mean send the old one, as in the old password in plaintext, a hash is one way, you can't (or at least shouldn't be able to) decrypt it. What you want to do really is send them a link which they can visit to reset their password that expires after a certain time/completion.

Comment: Can this link just be based on the user ID that the email is being sent to? @Pigeon

Comment: If you think about it, if you just had a link like `example.com/reset-password.php?id=55` and you sent that to the user, what would stop them from just changing the ID from 55 to 1, or another number. There are a lot of smarter people out there than me on google with solutions for one-time links for resetting passwords, a good starting point would probably be to read [OWAP's reccomendations/warnings](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Hashing uses one-way algorithms so you can't do this, I wouldn't advise sending passwords in plain text either.